# How to submit CSR to Windows CSR?

Tags: windows, java, ssl

I'm currently porting a script which generates an SSL key from a Windows CA (which usually runs using Microsoft Windows) to Ubuntu. Unfortunately, I've been unable to find a substitute for the Windows application `certreq`.

My script currently looks like this:

```
# Generate keystore with name ssl, write to cert.jks
keytool -genkey -dname "CN=my.host.bla, OU=[...], O=[...], L=[...], S=BY, C=DE" -alias ssl -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -keystore cert.jks

# gen CSR into my.host.bla.csr
keytool -certreq -keyalg RSA -alias ssl -file my.host.bla.csr -keystore cert.jks -ext san=DNS:my.host.bla

# submit CSR to CA (this is a windows-specifc part!!)
certreq -submit -attrib "certificatetemplate:ssl201610" my.host.bla.csr

# Import Issuers
# Root-CA: (already downloaded)
keytool -import -alias root-pki -keystore cert.jks -trustcacerts -file "blaRootCA.cer"

# Intermedi / Issuer-CA: (already downloaded)
keytool -import -alias issuing-pki -keystore cert.jks -trustcacerts -file "blaIssuingCA.cer"

# Import keys
keytool -import -alias ssl -keystore cert.jks -file my.host.bla.cer
```

The sole remaining question is: **Is there an application which replaces** `certreq`**?**

Everything else works fine

Comment: There is the Web Enrollment interface, but you should consider security before installing that on an Enterprise CA.

Comment: @garethTheRed thanks for you input, unluckily the web enrollment interface is not feasible here.

Comment: `certutil` uses Microsoft's own WCCE protocol for enrollment.  As far as I'm aware, there is no Linux client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unluckily there's really no client for that in linux, while the web interface might be a solution (for others), the most simple way is:

- moving the `csr` into a windows-based host
- doing the `certreq` step
- moving the `certificate` back to a linux-based host.